# How find closest word using TF Hub module?

Tags: tensorflow-hub

If np.inner between to embeddings return their similarity.
How can I find the closest word from one word embedding?
I'm using the Wiki module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
# Download 10k most popular english words.    
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt')
words = response.read().split("\n")

# Compute the embedding for 10k words.
with tf.Graph().as_default():
  embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/Wiki-words-250/1")
  embeddings = embed(words)
  with tf.train.MonitoredSession() as sess:
    values = sess.run(embeddings)

data = dict(zip(words, values))

def get_neighbors(all_data, target, count=3):
  # Compute points in all_data that are the closest to "target".
  # Sort the words based on the length of the vector between them.
  # Then pick "count" closest ones.
  return sorted(all_data, key=lambda emb_key: np.linalg.norm(all_data[emb_key] - target))[:count]

# Then make queries of your choice, e.g.
print(get_neighbors(data, data["first"]))
# Prints ['first', 'second', 'third'] 
print(get_neighbors(data, data["woman"] - data["man"] + data["father"], count=10))
# Prints ['mother', 'father', 'wife', 'daughter', 'wed', 'husband', 'uncle', 'son', 'child', 'mistress']
```